# mixed conditional sentence

Tags: conditional-constructions

Assumming that tommorrow my friend will take a examination, but he didn't study anything, so it's too late for him now, he is doomed for sure :). Is it grammatically correct if I say to my friend:

```
If you want to pass the test, you should have studied harder (in the past).
```

I did some research about mixed conditionals, but almost all the documents/blogs said that the if clause must be unreal conditionals. The verb *"want"* in my sentence is confusing me, I don't even know if it's likely (possible) situation or unreal (hypothetical) situation.

I know it is correct to say: *If you want to pass the test, you should study harder*. But in this sentence, I feel like he still has time to study.

Comment: Since it's too late now, I think the most natural thing to say would be _If you had wanted to pass the test, you should have studied harder_.

Comment: I  would use plain "wanted". "If you wanted to pass the test, you should have studied harder."